# Papyrus - Create a Table from an existing configuration

Tags: eclipse, papyrus

Which additional Papyrus component do I have to install to create a Requirements table from an existing configuration?

I´m working with Eclipse, Papyrus on Windows7 and I can´t find these options to create a table from an existing configuration, maybe I need to install a extra component but I can´t find which one do I need.

I've worked with this before, but on a Mac, now I´m on a Windows PC and can´t find these options, is it because of the operative system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the answer to my question:**

- The only way I found was to update Eclipse from Juno, to Kepler. When
  I did it new Papyrus Additional Components were avaliable, installing
  Papyrus Tabular Editors (Incubation) solved my problem of generating
  a Requirements Table from an existing configuration.